# css parts are missing when loading from wwwroot

Tags: html, css, web

I published a working version of my site to my wwwroot folder, but when I open the website some of the design is missing.
I looked in devTools (sources) in chrome and noticed that there are parts of my css that are missing, when I open the css manualy from the wwwroot folder I see that the parts are actualy there.
What might cause a selective css load?
The missing part of my css file:

```
#layer {
    background: url(http://s14.directupload.net/images/111129/44ga9qid.png);
    height: 550px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#slide {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menufixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-bottom: chocolate 8px solid;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

The whole css file as published to the wwwroot folder:

```
.menu_item {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 4px solid #B6B5B5;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px 2px 0px 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#Top {
    border-bottom: chocolate 8px solid;
    /* margin-bottom: 3%; */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

#Logo {
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3vw;
    background: url(http://www.elinorart.com/Gallery/latest%20artworks/slides/93.jpg) no-repeat, #5E5E5E;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 5% 0;
}


h1:hover {
    color: chocolate;
}

a:hover, a div:hover {
    color: chocolate;
}

#menu_bar {
    display: inline-block;
}

#contact_text {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /* font-weight: 600; */
    font-size: 16px;
    /* font-family: -webkit-pictograph; */
    color: #5E5E5E;
    /* letter-spacing: 0px; */
}

#bottom_left p {
    padding: 0px 49px 0 64px;
}

#bottom_center p {
    padding: 0px 62px 0 30px;
}

#contact_details {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#pageFooter {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

li {
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.exhibit_name {
    color: black;
}

#page {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.page_content {
    font-family: Arial;
    /*text-align: initial;*/
    /* background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); */
    /* padding-top: 3%; */
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

body.about_me {
    background-color: green;
}

.borderClass {
    border-color: chocolate;
}

#contactDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.contact_field {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #5E5E5E;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, cursive;
    width: 322px;
    height: 24px;
}

.contact_field_desc {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: left;
}

.send_form {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #5E5E5E;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 28px;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
}

#Facebook {
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* margin-left: 40%; */
    /* margin-top: 3%; */
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

#fb-root {
    /*float: left;*/
    vertical-align: central;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#fb-root2 {
    /*float: right;*/
    vertical-align: central;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fb_iframe_widget {
    /* margin-right: 13px; */
    /* float: left; */
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.exhibitions {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    float: left;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: left;
}

.exhibitions_wrapper {
    padding-right: 3%;
}

ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

    ul li ul li {
        list-style-type: initial;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

.exhibitions_year {
    /* margin-left: -5%; */
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
    font-size: 37px;
    /* line-height: 1px; */
    margin: 14px 0;
    color: orange;
    color: chocolate;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.bottom_sections {
    width: 25%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    /* padding: 2%; */
}

.bottom_content {
    /* padding: 0 10%; */
    text-align: center;
}

.buttom_text {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    text-align: left;
}

#AboutMe p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.contact_info {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#exhibitions_wrapper {
    width: 70%;
}

#AboutMe .wrapper {
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 3%;
    margin: 12px 0;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 37px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: dimgrey;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* padding: 15px; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    /* padding: 0; */
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: dimgrey;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#AboutMe .contact_field {
    width: 187px;
}

input {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.gallery_homepage {
    height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.gallery_homepage div {
    height: 550px;
}

#layer {
    background: url(http://s14.directupload.net/images/111129/44ga9qid.png);
    height: 550px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#slide {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menufixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-bottom: chocolate 8px solid;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: parts of a .css file? or some .css files are loaded and others aren't?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console window (in the browser dev tools)?

Comment: @mezod - there is one css file only and the missing parts are the above.

Comment: Did you make sure that the uploaded file has been correctly sent and has been received by the server? Is that code from your wwwroot folder or from your "working version of my site"?

Comment: This is the version from the wwwroot that is identical to the local one. But when running the site, the above part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for it:

1. Your CSS rule might be overridden by inline style
2. It may be overridden by other preceding rule (in the later lines) in the same CSS file
3. You might be over ridding the css using ' !important' (this can be seen in dev tools)
4. You might have an error in your CSS file such as wrong syntax or missing ';' after rule or missing '{' or '}' at the beginning or end  block of rules
5. Last but not least you might not be including the (correct) CSS file properly in the html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I checked the elements that need to be affected by the missing css styles (using inspect element) and there are no styles apllyed on them and also no override (if there were they would appear cross out in devTools). I have only one css file and when viewing its' content in devTools - most of it appears - only the above published css part is missing from that file.

Comment: did you check for syntax errors such as missing { or } or ; ??

Comment: yes, checked it and all looks fine - the missing part is the published above part. also tried moving it to other areas of the css file and still this exact part is missing every time.

Comment: can you edit your post and show us the whole css file?

Comment: Have you tried putting that css part in a seperate .css file?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similiar problem: I updated a HTML and a CSS file and uploaded it to the server. When reloading in the browser, the updates in the HTML file showed but those in the CSS didn't. That was because of the way the browser (in my case Chrome) is caching. When opening in an Inkognito-Tab or deleting the cache it did work.